# Parameter in function in c++ (Object* &var)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the asterisk "*" before a type declaration in function. I have the following structure:

```
struct TrieNode
{
    // Each node stores a map to its child nodes
    unordered_map<char, TrieNode*> map;
    // true when node is a leaf
    bool isLeaf = false;
    // Collection with list of word in leaf node
    unordered_set<string> word;
};

void insert(TrieNode* &head, string word) {
    // If not exists the trie, create it
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = new TrieNode();
    }

    // Start from the head node
    TrieNode* curr = head;
    for (char c: word) {
        // Insert the letter;
        // But, first, check if the node not already completed
        if (curr->map.find(c) == curr->map.end()) {
            curr->map[c] = new TrieNode();
        }
        // Update the element on map
        curr = curr->map[c];
    }
    // Mark as end of letter
    curr->isLeaf = true;
    (curr->word).insert(word);
}
```

My question is: Why the asterisk on line 4 (on `TrieNode*`) and line 11 (again, on `TrieNode*`). What this asterisk do?

Thanks!

Comment: `TrieNode*` declares a pointer to type `TrieNode` - that's very basic stuff that every good C++ book should explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` in a declaration like `TrieNode* curr = head;` declares that the variable `curr` is a *pointer* to a `TrieNode` struct. In your function definition, `void insert(TrieNode* &head, string word)`, the parameter, `head`, is also declared as a pointer to a `TrieNode` structure; the following `&` symbol means that the parameter is passed *by reference*, meaning that any changes to the *value* of `head` in the function will *also* be reflected in the value of the passed variable in the calling module.

Comment: It might also help to think of it as `TrieNode** head` like we had to use in the dark ages before `&` arrived, as we chiseled our code into stone tablets.  Passing by reference hides the second `*` from you along with changing all the `*head = ` into just `head = `